# Discord Bot not reading and sending at text channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've made the following bot to play RPS with another element.

`import discord
import random

```
TOKEN = 'SEU_TOKEN_AQUI'
PREFIX = '+'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'Bot {client.user} está online!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.content.startswith(PREFIX + 'test'):
    await jogar_pedra_papel_tesoura(message)

if message.content.startswith(PREFIX + 'testb'):
    await jogar_pedra_papel_tesoura_com_bomba(message)

async def jogar_pedra_papel_tesoura(message):
escolhas = ['Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura']
escolha_bot = random.choice(escolhas)
escolha_usuario = message.content[len(PREFIX + 'test'):].strip().capitalize()

if escolha_usuario not in escolhas:
    await message.channel.send("Escolha inválida. Use 'Pedra', 'Papel' ou 'Tesoura'.")
    return

if escolha_bot == escolha_usuario:
    resultado = 'Empate!'
elif (escolha_bot == 'Pedra' and escolha_usuario == 'Tesoura') or (escolha_bot == 'Tesoura'      and escolha_usuario == 'Papel') or (escolha_bot == 'Papel' and escolha_usuario == 'Pedra'):
    resultado = f'O bot escolheu {escolha_bot}. Você perdeu!'
else:
    resultado = f'O bot escolheu {escolha_bot}. Você venceu!'

await message.channel.send(resultado)

async def jogar_pedra_papel_tesoura_com_bomba(message):
escolhas = ['Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura', 'Bomba']
escolha_bot = random.choice(escolhas)
escolha_usuario = message.content[len(PREFIX + 'testb'):].strip().capitalize()

if escolha_usuario not in escolhas:
    await message.channel.send("Escolha inválida. Use 'Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura' ou 'Bomba'.")
    return

if escolha_bot == escolha_usuario:
    resultado = 'Empate!'
elif (escolha_bot == 'Pedra' and escolha_usuario == 'Tesoura') or (escolha_bot == 'Tesoura' and escolha_usuario == 'Papel') or (escolha_bot == 'Papel' and escolha_usuario == 'Pedra'):
    resultado = f'O bot escolheu {escolha_bot}. Você perdeu!'
elif escolha_bot == 'Bomba' and escolha_usuario != 'Papel':
    resultado = f'O bot escolheu {escolha_bot}. Você venceu!'
else:
    resultado = f'O bot escolheu {escolha_bot}. Você perdeu!'

await message.channel.send(resultado)

client.run(TOKEN)`
```

The problem is... command works in bot's DM but not working on channels.

I want that this bot read the message at my server channel and post the results.
Right now its work through DMs, but i want to work at Channels

1.It works in DMs

2.The bot is online and working

3.The bot has all the permissions needed

Comment: enable `message_content` intent.

Comment: Even with message content intent enable at bot configs, still not working

Comment: Edit your code and fix the indentation.

Comment: @PedroDiniz, [welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) I don't think `message_content` would be enough. IIRC, you need something for guilds, so it's better to use `intents = discord.Intents.all()` instead of `intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False`. And enable all the permissions in your Discord Developer Portal. And yes, fix your indentation.